# Unable to negate condition in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have table for storing people following other people. Two columns. I can query those who a certain user follows (and has a certain book) by

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
 SELECT USERS.NAME, USERS.NAME2
 FROM USERS
 LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.USERID = USERS.ID
 LEFT JOIN FOLLOW ON FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = USERS.ID
 WHERE USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ? AND FOLLOW.USER_ID = ?
");
$stmt -> execute(array($bookid, $session_userid));
```

However, I have no idea how to query those that I don't follow. I cannot simply modify the WHERE clause to ... AND NOT FOLLOW.USER_ID = ?
because the result will consist those as well that I already follow. The following table is an example where USER_ID is the one who follows and FOLLOW_ID is who is being followed.

```
ROW USER_ID FOLLOW_ID
1      6      1
2     15      5
3     13      8
4     15      10
5     15      12
6      4      5
```

The result of the first query is row No. #2,#4,#5 because USER_ID No.15 follows those three users. However, when I say `NOT FOLLOW.USER_ID = ?` the result will be row No. #1,#3,#6, meaning users 1,8,5. But I already follow user 5, so how do I do this? I need only two rows as the result: #1 and #3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `NOT EXISTS` with a sub-query:

```
 SELECT USERS.NAME, USERS.NAME2
 FROM USERS
 LEFT JOIN USERS_BOOKS ON USERS_BOOKS.USERID = USERS.ID
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM FOLLOW
   WHERE FOLLOW.USER_ID = ?
   AND FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID = USERS.ID
 )
 AND USERS_BOOKS.BOOKID = ?
```

Comment: This results in everyone who I am not following and ignores the expression that they have that book.

Comment: I was including both conditions in the "not exists" - didn't realize you wanted to keep one and negate the other. Try it now. Do note that the userid and the bookid need to switch order now.

Comment: It looks like it gives the correct result but I had to change `FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID` back to `USERS.ID` in the ON clause, otherwise I got `Unknown column 'FOLLOW.FOLLOW_ID' in 'on clause'`.

Comment: Yes, it's hard to get it all right without any way to test it. If this answered your questions please mark it as the accepted answer.